# Understanding Example 2.2 in AT on pg.106.

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

The example is given below:

> [image]

**My Questions are:**

1- In the first line, why "then $\vartriangle_{0} (S^1)$ and  $\vartriangle_{1} (S^1)$ are both $\mathbb{Z}$" ?

2-I do not understand the last paragraph in the given picture. could anyone explain it for me, please?

3-Is the homology group of the circle equal to its simplicial homology group?

Comment: Question 1 should be an *immediate* application of the definition of $\Delta_n(X)$ given earlier in the section. Are you having trouble with that definition?

Comment: @LeeMosher yes I have trouble https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447820/need-an-example-of-applying-the-definition-of-a-boundary-homomorphism?noredirect=1#comment7087587_3447820

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer $1$, you'll find earlier in the chapter that $\Delta_n(X)$ is defined to be the free abelian group with a generator for every $n$-simplex in $X$.

In this example, the number of $0$-simplices (= vertices) is $1$, because there is just one vertex $v$. So $\Delta_0(X)$ is the free abelian group on 1 generator (and every free abelian group on $1$ generator is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$), and he is calling that 1 generator $v$.

Also, the number of $1$-simplices (= edges) is $1$ because there is just one edge $e$. So again $\Delta_1(X)$ is the free abelian group on $1$ generator, which is isomorhpic to $\mathbb Z$, and he is calling that $1$ generator $e$.

To answer $2$, he has computed $\partial_1 e = v - v = 0$. Therefore, $\partial_1 : \Delta_1(X) \mapsto \Delta_0(X)$ takes the generator $e$ to zero. Therefore $\partial_1$ is the zero homomorphism. It's even easier to see that every other boundary map in this chain complex is also the zero homomorphism because either its domain or its range is the trivial group.

Now I'll leave you to work it out: what's the kernel and the range of a zero homomorphism? How do you use that to compute the homology groups, when all the boundary maps are zero homomorphisms?

Your question 3 is not well formulated. I expect you did not intend to ask "Is the **simplicial** homology group of a circle equal to its simplicial homology group", but then I would wonder what *kind* of homology group you are really asking about? There is a more advanced theorem that Hatcher is working up to in that portion of the book, which says that the singular homology group of any $\Delta$ complex is *isomorphic to* (not equal to) its simplicial homology group.

Comment: For Q.1, Yes, I found the definition you mentioned on pg.104 of AT the last two lines. my question is how to find the basis of $X$? Also on the next page it says that $\vartriangle_{n}(X)$ can be written as the formal sums $\sum_{\alpha}$ ..... specifically this paragraph is hard for me to understand. what is the difference between $\vartriangle_{n} $ and  $\vartriangle^{n} $?

Comment: Very very very clear and nice explanation for 1 thank you so much :))

Comment: You can find $\Delta^n$ define on page 103. You can find $\Delta_n(X)$ defined on page 104. And if you need to learn about free abelian groups and their bases, then you may need an algebra book.

Comment: So the homology groups are 0 because they are 0/0 ..... correct?

Comment: For the third question, the OP is asking this question because our professor is asking us to compute the homology groups of the torus, and when we asked him which homology do you need us to prove, he\she said they are the same ...... so I understood that they are equal ..... but when I checked Hatcher (if I remember correctly ) I found that they are not equal ...... am I correct? the results of calculating the simplicial homology, singular homology and cellular homology groups are different.